# Is it ever convenient to maximize different functions of the likelihood than the logarithm?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, logarithm, likelihood

We all know that it's often much more convenient to maximize the log-likelihood rather than the likelihood to get a parameter estimate, since it amounts to the same thing by the fact that the logarithm function is continuous and strictly increasing. It ends up simplifying exponential terms, turns products into sums, has lots of other nice analytical properties, and it's often more numerically stable than maximizing the raw likelihood.

However, you could also maximize say, the cube-root of the likelihood if you were so inclined, or indeed use any other order-preserving function. Does this ever actually make any problems easier, or is the logarithm really the only game in town?

Answer (score 1):

No. You do log to transform a product into a sum, which is convenient in optimization because it makes derivatives easier to deal with. The monotonicity of log is just a necessary pre-condition for such a transformation to be useful. The fact that a power function is monotonic doesn't do any service for dealing with a product.